# Why is threaded Random SO slow, - ( Or where is my code wrong! )

Tags: c++, optimization, random, thread-safety, openmp

I've been having trouble getting a threaded C++ Random number generator to outperform the standard rand() on a single core. (I do also see issues with multiple threads calling rand() )

I know there are concurrency issues somewhere, but I can't see it. I've got to the below and I know openmp is splitting across the 8 available cores. When I comment out the omp lines, I get the faster results. Please help! This is driving me crazy!

The times

```
Single thread
time ./a.out 
real    0m3.497s
user    0m3.492s
sys 0m0.000s

OpemMP 8 cores
g++ -fopenmp randtests.cpp 
time ./a.out 
real    0m14.723s
user    1m52.275s
sys 0m0.712s
```

The Code:

```
#include <omp.h>        
#include "boost/random.hpp"
#include "boost/generator_iterator.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "boost/random.hpp"

using namespace std;

class RNG
{
public:
    typedef boost::random::mt19937 Engine;
    typedef boost::random::uniform_smallint<int> Distribution;

    Engine engine;
    Distribution distributer;

    RNG() : engine(), distributer() {
        engine.seed();     }

    int operator()() {
        return distributer(engine);
    }
};


int main(void) {

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i = omp_get_thread_num();
        unsigned int myseed = i;
        RNG  r;
        int y;
#pragma omp for ordered schedule(dynamic) nowait
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < 100000000; x++) {
            y = r();
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each thread should have its own generator.

Comment: @Pete That does not necessarily guarantee a properly random sequence across all threads (depends on the used generator and seeds). Works well for linear congruential RNGs with different additive constants or lagged fibbonacci generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons for your code to execute so slowly.

First, you have the `schedule(dynamic)` clause. This makes the scheduling of your loop dynamic, i.e. each iteration is scheduled to a separate thread on a first come, first served basis. This is extremely inefficient. Use `schedule(static)` instead to have each thread execute a precomputed range of iterations. Uniform distributions are generated in constant time so each iteration would take the same amount of time, hence no need to use dynamic scheduling.

Second, you have instructed the compiler to create an ordered parallel loop. Ordering incurs very high additional overhead due to the synchronisation involved. In you case the overhead is even bigger, since the scheduling is dynamic.

I don't really get it why you have both dynamic schedule and ordering in this case. Simply replace the OpenMP pragma with:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
```

(the `nowait` clause also has only superficial influence in this case)

Comment: Thanks Hristo, Across 8 cores with the mt19937, im about 20% faster than single thread access to rand. Could you suggest anything to push the speed further? maybe a different engine? - Better randomness is not a big concern, much more interested in throughput

Comment: How about `erand48()`? It is similar to `rand()`, but its state vector is 48 bits long, so it provides better PRN streams.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. Reg the OpenMP Shows why some things should be carefully checked instead of copying from examples. I can't believe the speed gains this is getting. I need to check through some old code!

Comment: You've probably copied from some very bad OpenMP example. Ordered dynamic loops make almost no sense (to me).

Comment: @joeButler If you want a good scaling parallel PRNG, you probably don't want to use the ones provided by the standard (haven't looked into it, but they're probably more focused on the single threaded version). You should probably be able to get a close to linear speedup if you write it yourself. I'll write something up about that later tonight if I don't forget ;)

Comment: @Voo I would be very interested in that. My application will benefit, but I'm also getting very curious myself having spend a good few hours looking into solutions

Comment: @Voo, all standard PRNGs provide reentrant versions where the state is provided explicitly, e.g. `rand_r()` and `drand48_r()`. If the state vectors remain far apart in memory as is the case when they are allocated on the stacks of different threads, then no false sharing occurs and the PRNGs will be as performant as in the single-threaded case.

Comment: If you are interested in high performance (both in quality and speed) parallel random number generators, then you should read John Salmon, Mark Moraes, Ron Dror and David Shaw : “Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy As 1, 2, 3.” (Best paper at SC11)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly convinced that the threads are competing for a shared resource, namely that of the `state` in the random number generator. For each number you fetch, the `state` is updated (to give another number next time). Since there is only one state for all of your random numbers, and it needs to be updated without interference from other threads, it will force the threads to run sequentially (and because the lock is heavily contended when you have 8 threads calling the same function, and thus forces the other thread to wait, it probably means more time is spent calling into the OS).

Another factor may well be cache-sharing - the `state` is modified by all threads, so the cache-lines holding the state will have to be invalidated every time `r()` is called.

. You can prove this by replacing your call to `distributer(engine)` with something like `static int x; return x++;`. If performs worse (than linearly better per number of threads) in a multi-process environment, then cache-sharing is part of the problem.

Comment: The state of Boost's `mt19937` is not shared and each thread has its own stack so neither true nor false sharing occurs.

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for answering. I was expecting something like you described to be going on, but it turns out that incrementing the static int runs faster, ie no competition. Was just a case of me using  openmp badly.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's much more of a good answer for this particular question.